# python3: can't open file 'notebook': errno 2 no such file or directory

Tags: python3, jupyter

I am facing issues with running spark in Jupyter notebook. 
I have following variables set in /.bashrc

```
export SPARK_HOME=~/Development/Spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' pyspark
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

When I type pyspark, I am getting the error

> python3: can't open file 'notebook': errno 2 no such file or directory

For me 'jupyter notebook' is opening up a notebook in browser.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

> **TL;DR** Check that the environment variables `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` are not set in *spark-env.sh*.

I ran into a similar issue after setting up Spark using a book before taking a Pyspark Udemy course.

After scouring StackOverflow and troubleshooting, it turned out that I had defined the environment variables `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` in both my ~/.bashrc and spark-env.sh, as shown below.

*~/.bashrc*

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=~/anaconda3/bin/python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
```

*spark-env.sh*

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
```

The **solution** for me was to **remove** the lines in the *spark-env.sh*. I was then able to start jupyter notebook by running the `pyspark` command and utilize pyspark within the notebook. It is expected that the `jupyter notebook` command should open jupyter notebooks in a browser.

Hope this helps!